# send fetch params using a const in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, get, fetch

I am doing a GET fetch request like this:

```
let [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: headers,
            cache: 'no-cache',
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            credentials: 'include',
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) return response.json();
                throw new Error('Request failed.');
            })
            .then(data => {
                setResponseData(data); // sent user data to redux
                dispatch(props.setUser(data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);
```

But I want to put all the fetch request parameters in a const and call that const inside the fetch function like this:

```
let [responseData, setResponseData] = React.useState('');
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const fetchData = React.useCallback(() => {
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        });
        const reqParams = {
            method: 'GET',
            mode: 'cors',
            headers: headers,
            cache: 'no-cache',
            redirect: 'follow',
            referrer: 'no-referrer',
            credentials: 'include',
        }
        fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', {
           reqParams, 
        })
            .then(response => {
                if (response.ok) return response.json();
                throw new Error('Request failed.');
            })
            .then(data => {
                setResponseData(data); // sent user data to redux
                dispatch(props.setUser(data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }, []);
    React.useEffect(() => {
        fetchData();
    }, [fetchData]);
```

But this is not making a successful fetch call. What am I doing wrong, I can not figure out the error here. How can I write that function properly.

Comment: seems because of  `fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', {reqParams, })` this line. have you tried `fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', reqParams )` ? 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not work because the params are nested under the `reqParams` key.

It should be

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', reqParams)
```

Note that

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', {
  reqParams, 
})
```

is the same as

```js
fetch('http://localhost:3000/current_user', {
  reqParams: {
    method: 'GET',
    mode: 'cors',
    headers,
    cache: 'no-cache',
    redirect: 'follow',
    referrer: 'no-referrer',
    credentials: 'include',
  }
})
```